# CSS absolute positioned div heights

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have  the following structure of my HTML document:

```
<div id="slideshow"></div>
<div id="content"></div>

$('#slideshow').css({
   'height' : $('#content').innerHeight()+'px'
})
```

The **#slideshow** div is positioned absolute with a lower z-index and the **#content** div is positioned relatively with height set to auto.

Question: How do I ensure that the height of slideshow is also set to auto and according tho the height of the content?

I even tried jQuery `.innerheight()` property with no luck.

Comment: Please post some of your code. If you could put it on jsFiddle for us, that'd be very useful.

Comment: Can you include the HTML or even better create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: well this is the jQuery part
[code]$('#slideshow').css({
      
    // 'height' : $('#content').innerHeight()+'px'
      
    })[/code]
and the html structure 
[code]<div id="slideshow"></div><div id="content"></div>[/code]

Comment: Neil - i have added the code from your comment into your questions (you can edit the question) - can you add the CSS too ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your content can be resized dinamically (for example by adding new content, or dragging a textarea in browsers such as Chrome), you should include the jquery resize plugin, and a callback that fires whenever your content div is resized.

If the only way your content can be resized is in a window resize, you dont need to include jquery resize, and then you should bind the resize event to the window object $(window).resize(....);

If your content cant be resized in any way, then just calling to the updateSize() method will do. You can check it in the following link, but I suggest you to check it in Chrome and resize the textarea so you can test how the slideshow box is also updated.

http://jsfiddle.net/qFE6b/2/

```
var updateSize = function(){
    $('#slideshow').height( $('#content').height()  );     
};

$("#content").resize(updateSize);


updateSize ();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jphellemons/qFE6b/

```
$('#slideshow').height($('#content').height());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way:

http://jsfiddle.net/peduarte/zTATa/